# Directory and files stuck on server after upload

Tags: apache-2.2, php, upload

I've uploaded some files into a directory i've created (using a php upload script). At first I didn't set the right chmod for dir. and files (411 instead of 777). Now this folder and files are stuck on the server, can't delete using FTP, cant delete using script: unlink/rmdir. I don't have server acces. Is there any way to still do this using PHP scripting?

Comment: As long as you have created the directory you should be the owner and with 700 permission you can delete the directory (and the files in it)

Comment: Now the permissions are 411. I am sure they were 700 earlier...

Comment: But user and owner are the same: apache. When I upload files to a directory which is set to 775 (using the upload script) owner and user are also apache AND I'm able to delete them. So only difference are the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If

```
chmod ("/somedir/somefile", 755); // php script code
```

does not work you still can try

```
unlink($filename);  // php script code
```

and

```
rmdir($dirname);  // php script code
```

to remove them. If this does not work then your apache-account on the server does not have the necessary rights to do that. I guess this should usually work cause your apache-account created those files.

Comment: I understand, and this *should* work. But not in this case. (see my comments on the original question)

Answer (score 0):

There is PHP's [chmod filesystem function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php), assuming PHP's process is the owner of dir, you can change permissions using it.